# php - compare multi arrays and output in order

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have two arrays:
Array 1:

```
$art_style = ['Title1','Title2','Title3'];
```

Array 2:

```
array(
  'name' => array('Title1', 'Title3', 'Title2'), 
  'value' => array('2,0x1,0', '2,5', '15,0'
);
```

I need to compare Array 2 "name" with Array 1 and output the values from Array 2 in the order of Array 1.

So the output in this case would be:
2,0x1,0 - 15,0 - 2,5

Any Idea how I could achieve that?

Comment: `foreach(array1 as $t) { $new[] = $array2['value'][array_search( $t, array2['name'])]; }`

Comment: I had almost exactly splashs idea but with array_keys()

Comment: @Marek123  don't forget to test that array_serch returns not false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
// Array1 order

foreach ($art_style as $key => $value) {
    if(in_array($value,$array2['name']))
        echo $array2['value'][$key];
}

// Array2 order

foreach ($array2['name'] as $key => $value) {
    if(in_array($value,$art_style))
        echo $array2['value'][$key];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Little Long Method. But, It Worked.

```
<?
$array1 = ['Title1','Title2','Title3'];  

$array2=array(
  'name' => array('Title1', 'Title3', 'Title2'), 
  'value' => array('2,0x1,0', '2,5', '15,0')
);  


$SizeofArray2=sizeof($array2['name']);

for($i=0;$i<$SizeofArray2;$i++)
{
    $Array2Value= $array2['name'][$i];

    for($j=0;$j<sizeof($array1);$j++)
    {
        if($Array2Value==$array1[$j])
        {
            if($j==$i)          
            {
            echo " ".$array2['value'][$i];
            }
            if($j!=$i)
            {
            echo " -".$array2['value'][$i];
            }
        }
    }

}
?>
```

Output: 2,0x1,0 -2,5 -15,0

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$art_style = array('Title1','Title2','Title3'); 

$array2 = array(
  'name' => array('Title1', 'Title3', 'Title2'), 
  'value' => array('2,0x1,0', '2,5', '15,0')
);

foreach ($art_style as $style) {
    foreach ($array2['name'] as $id => $name) {
        if ($name == $style) {
            echo $array2['value'][$id].' - ';
            break;
        }
    }
}
```